# Check if a DLL is already registered

Tags: c++, registry, clsid

I am trying to use GetClassFile function passing the DLL name as a parameter and expecting the function to return CLSID. Then using CoCreateInstance, I could check if the dll is registered or not.

I am not able to get a valid return for `GetClassFile()` even when passing a registered DLL.

```
HRESULT hr = GetClassFile((LPCOLESTR) "C:\\Program Files\\Common Files\\Microsoft Shared\\DAO\\dao360.dll", &clsid);
```

Comment: The (LPCOLESTR) cast only stopped the compiler from telling you were doing it wrong, it didn't stop you from doing it wrong.  Use an L instead, like GetClassFile(L"etcetera").

Answer (score 1):

`GetClassFile()` is not related to COM. If you read the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms693715.aspx), passing a DLL filename will not produce a COM CLSID that you can pass to `CoCreateInstance()`. It will always fail with a `MK_E_INVALIDEXTENSION` error.

What you can do is call `LoadTypeLib()` to check if the DLL implements a type library and retrieve its `ITypeLib` interface. If successful, you can then call its `GetTypeInfoCount()`, `GetTypeInfoType()`, and `GetTypeInfo()` methods to locate and retrieve the `ITypeInfo` interface for each `TKIND_COCLASS` object. For each `ITypeInfo`, you can call its  `GetTypeAttr()` method to retrieve its `CLSID`. Once you have that, you can call `CoCreateInstance()` requesting the `IUnknown` interface to check the registration (or you could just manually check the `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\<clsid>` key of the Registry).

Comment: "For each ITypeInfo, you can call its GetTypeAttr() method to retrieve its CLSID"..................but i dont find how to get the CLSID frm GetTypeAttr. I can do this GUID classGUID = typeattr->guid. But that doestn give any CLSID. PLEASE HELP.

Comment: When `ITypeLib::GetTypeInfoType()` returns `TKIND_COCLASS` then the corresponding `ITypeInfo::GetTypeAttr()` returns the CLSID in the `TYPEATTR::guid` member.